# React onwheel not performing existing scrollintoview but onclick is able to

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const Index = () => {
// Ref Links
const frefLinks = {
  1: useRef(1),
  2: useRef(2),
  3: useRef(3),
  4: useRef(4),
  5: useRef(5),
};

const scrollLink = (i) => {
  let frefLink = frefLinks[i];
  return frefLink.current.scrollIntoView({
    block: "start",
    behavior: "smooth"
  });
};

return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <style.globalStyle/>
    <NavMenu
          scrollToLinkA={() => { scrollLink(1) }}
          scrollToLinkB={() => { scrollLink(2) }}
          scrollToLinkC={() => { scrollLink(3) }}
          scrollToLinkD={() => { scrollLink(4) }}
          scrollToLinkE={() => { scrollLink(5) }}
    />
    <Sect1 fref={frefLinks[1]} onWheel={e => e.deltaY <= 0 ? console.log('up') : scrollLink(2) }/>
    <Sect2 fref={frefLinks[2]} onWheel={e => e.deltaY <= 0 ? scrollLink(1) : scrollLink(3) }/>
    <Sect3 fref={frefLinks[3]} onWheel={e => e.deltaY <= 0 ? () => { scrollLink(2) } : () => { scrollLink(4) } }/>
    <Sect4 fref={frefLinks[4]} onWheel={e => e.deltaY <= 0 ? scrollLink(3) :scrollLink(5) }/>
    <Sect5 fref={frefLinks[5]} onWheel={e => e.deltaY <= 0 ? scrollLink(4) :console.log('down')}/>
  </React.Fragment>
);
}
```

scrollToLinkA to E are nested div's onClick event. **It works perfectly for onclick**, onWheel is correct in the Section's nested div. `div onWheel = {onwheel}` However, onwheel event is not firing the scroll function though console.log still works. I tried both normal calling the function and via arrow at Sect3's onwheel but it still fails.

I searched hard enough on react+onwheel+scrollintoview but I really cannot find any applicable answers. I'm not looking into onscroll, just onwheel is what i want.

I really want to reuse the scrollLink function and not adding extra window listener event or dependency. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if scrollLink function is not calling by onWheel, but I can be 100% sure that scrollLink is working properly as it is from onClick. I put console.log inside scrollLink and it logs too.

I have nav and section. nav's div's onClick fires scrollLink function and scrollintoview works perfectly. Now I'm doing section's div's onWheel event to fire the same 'scrollLink' function, it is not responding but console.log is working everywhere.

I can't post comment anymore so I'm posting here.